# Development server using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer not working?

Tags: php, pear, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I'm running the latest PHP and pear on a windows machine with `apache`
`2.4` (XAMPP), I have installed the latest versions of `OLE`, `PEAR` and
`Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer`. `PEAR` is installed and working.

However now instead of generating a download for the excel file on a
specific page (`generateexcel.php`) and redirecting to the previous page, the
page (`generateexcel.php`) is actually displayed (in the `url` with specific paramenters according to the date selected), it is blank. In the hosted
version it works perfectly and is on a linux based server with `apache 2.0` with `PHP 5.3.18`.

So basically on my development version it is not working, it is
connecting to database and everything else on the site is working.

Is this a problem with the `include_once` and `require_once` for the
`Writer.php` and the relative paths being incorrect because of being on
windows.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Even if I could get some kind of error reporting it would be very useful. I will try: `PEAR::isError()` in the meantime.

Comment: try to include error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning of your script. Do you see any error now, e.g. missing extensions?

Comment: thanks jamie, appreciate it...got an error from mySQL whereby i had to set and flush priveleges

Comment: great - I had trouble with this package recently as well. The OLE package cannot handle utf-8 very well in all cases and I had to patch it. Some hours lost.. ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure the version of `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer` and `OLE` are consistent with the code.

ie. Uninstall and use previous versions, the same versions used on the server or when initial coding went down.